# Fix for first borrow used after second mutable borrow in rust

Tags: rust

I have a toy problem where I am trying to push a mutable reference onto a stack. The mutable reference being pushed is obtained from a vector held in the top most element of the stack.

```
struct Node {
    name: String,
    children: Vec<Node>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut root = Node {
        name: String::from("/"),
        children: Vec::new(),
    };

    let mut stack: Vec<&mut Node> = Vec::new();
    stack.push(&mut root);

    // first mutable borrow occurs here
    let top = stack.last_mut().unwrap();
    let children = &mut top.children;
    for node in children.iter_mut() {
        if node.name == "asdf" {
            // second mutable borrow occurs here
            // FIXME: first borrow later used here
            stack.push(node);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I sorta get that the second mutable borrow should only occur after all code referenced in the block by the first mutable borrow is no longer in use. Though I am not certain whether the pattern I am trying to implement is impossible to achieve in Rust, or if there is an alternative that could help here.

Comment: *"Though I am not certain whether the pattern I am trying to implement is impossible to achieve in Rust"* - I'm not sure either :) It would help if you would describe said pattern. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The pattern here is mutating a vector by pushing a reference obtained from a value contained in an element whose reference was already pushed into the stack.

Comment: I don't think this is easily achievable, at least not with `&mut` references.